# session_start() causes server to run full execution time, then return data

Tags: php, session, ubuntu

I've got a small MVC application that I've been writing locally on my laptop with MAMP, and it runs fine - there's no issues, in fact, I've installed it on a GoDaddy server to use for a small project. I have an old computer in my house that I turned into an Ubuntu server with a LAMP installation and it works fine too. I looked around at questions online, but none seem to be the same situation.

I timed it; the page sits and loads for 60 seconds - the max execution time, and then displays. It's not a big site; at the moment it's literally a div with the word "demo" in it, some css and js. I sat and kept refreshing the access log on the server, and it doesn't add new records until the 60 seconds is up and the files are downloaded, so it's definitely not load time.

If I put `die('asdf');` down the index file, it works until I hit `session_start()`. I have another virtual server on the box, and it works with no problems whatsoever (even uses sessions).

If I comment out sessions, it runs until it hits an anonymous function, but I think the root of all of it is sessions. The server is running PHP 5.3.6 so it shouldn't be an issue.

I originally thought it was the .htaccess file, but I managed to rule that out.  I'm not the most server tech-savvy person out there, but I'm learning! I haven't modified anything with sessions on the server and so I can't imagine what's going to make it do this and not send any errors (everything is turned up as high as I can get it). I just feel like I should be getting a timeout error, not let it run and then sit until it times out. Again, the code works on two other servers so it's something on this server.

Thank you!

Comment: It could have something to do with the path where the session is stored (usually something like /var/tmp or something like that). Check what that path is (using `phpinfo()`) and check if that dir exists and is writeable for the webuser.

Comment: @Lex the thing I don't understand is that both sites on the server share a php.ini file, and session works fine on the other site. I mean, I'll check when I get home, but I don't understand how one would work and one wouldnt.

Comment: The file permissions on the temp folder are a property of the server, not of PHP. So if you run the same PHP configuration on two different servers, one of which has no write permissions in the folder where the sessions are stored, you will get an error.

Comment: I think you mixed up how I phrased that - the server with the issue already has another site on it. It's got two virtual servers, and they use the same php.ini file (literally the same file on the same server) - everything is configured the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a later version of PHP. I used to develop on MAMP with PHP 5.3.6, like you, and had some funky things happen (like closures not working with references properly).

I understand if your production environment cannot upgrade, but it would be worth a shot to see if it's a PHP problem or a script problem.

Comment: What's the current version of PHP? I thought 5.3.6 was the latest - and that's whats running on the server, not MAMP (although MAMP might be running that too, I'm at work and cannot check at the moment)